# Asynchronous Javascript function not working in html script

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, chart.js

I'm trying to run an asynchronous function that produces a chart.js chart in an html script, but nothing is showing up. It works when I change the code to be synchronous with dummy data.

html canvas with chart location:

```
<div class="tile is-4 is-parent">
  <div class="tile is-child box">
    <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```

html script:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="profile.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  makeBTCWeeklyLineChart()
</script>
```

profile.js:

```
const axios = require('axios')
const config = require(path.resolve(__dirname, "./config.js"))
const moment = require('moment')

const json = require("json")

async function makeBTCWeeklyLineChart() {
  let chrt = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d")
  let obj = await getBTCweekly()
  let data = {
    labels: obj.labels,
    datasets: [
      {
        label: "Weekly Market Cap",
        backgroundColor: "#0B244399", 
        borderColor: "#0B244399",
        hoverBackgroundColor: "#0B244399",
        hoverBorderColor: "#0B244399",
        data: obj.data
      }
    ]
  }
  let myFirstChart = new Chart(chrt, {
    type: "line",
    data: data,
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'BTC Weekly Market Cap'
      },
      scales: {
        xAxes: [{
          type:       "time",
          time:       {
              format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  })
}

async function getBTCweekly(){
  let response = await axios.get('https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=DIGITAL_CURRENCY_WEEKLY&symbol=BTC&market=USD&apikey=' + config.apikey)
  let obj = { labels: [], data: [] }
  const data = response.data['Time Series (Digital Currency Weekly)']
  for(let key in data){
    obj.labels.push(key)
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      obj.data.push(parseFloat(data[key]['6. market cap (USD)']))
    }
  }
  return obj
}
```

I've tried everything I can think of. To me it seems like the page is loading before the script has time to finish, but I've read elsewhere that the script should be running to completion before the html finishes parsing. There is a small possibility that it is a json formatting issue but I don't believe any of the chart input is incorrect. I am really at a loss.

Comment: Any console errors? Have you inserted `console.log` statements (or `debugger`) to check what's running when?

Comment: I put a console.log after the let obj = await getBTCweekly() line and it prints nothing for some reason.

Comment: Hrm, I'd say to check to see if the network request is going through properly (check network tab), but I'd have thought there would be an exception of some sort if it didn't work

Comment: You are using `require(axios)` etc in the browser. How is that working? Are you using a module loader somewhere or webpack? `profile.js` looks more like a node.js script meant to run on the server.

Comment: @Mark_M I don't know what you mean. I don't have a module loader or webpack.

Comment: You should look in your browser's error console. You will probably see an reference error about `require`.

Comment: @Mark_M You're right. 'ReferenceError: axios is not defined' and 'Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'. How to fix this?

Comment: If you don't want to use something like webpack, you should load your dependencies in `<script>` tags. Like: `<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>` . Not sure what your `config` does, but a remote browser isn't going to be able load something from a local path, so you'll need to get the config variables into the browser some other way.

Comment: @Mark_M Thanks very very much. I was trying to act like node was vanilla javascript.

Comment: post your example on JSFiddle, it might help to understand it